# Having an issue mapping to Linux Samba share from my Win 10

Tags: iptables, windows, opensuse, samba

I have a Samba share setup on a OpenSuse 12.2 machine. So it's using SMB 1.0.  Now a few months ago I use to be able to map a network drive to that share with no problem.  But now all of a sudden I have getting a popup error that says

"The mapped network drive count not be created because the following error has occurred:

The specified server cannot perform the requested operation"

At this point I don't know what to do to resolve this.  I haven't made any changes to my Win 10 machine nor have I made any changes to my Linux server.  Also other machines in our enviorment can map to the Samba share with now problem.

Lastly in looking at `/var/log/firewall`. I see my IP address in there logged at a SSH brute force back in Aug.

```
Aug 25 15:42:04 law-amp2 kernel: [245786868.074851] SSH brute force IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=d4:ae:52:a0:54:c5:e4:54:e8:ac:fb:af:08:00 SRC=10.69.174.58 DST=10.69.174.150 LEN=52 TOS=0x00           PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=15448 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1319 DPT=22 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

I do SSH to this server from time to time to administer it and that still works with no problem.  I am just wondering if the server is some how dropping my SMB connection.  At this point I have no idea why I all of a sudden can't map to my SAMBA share.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error could be because the SMBv1 protocol. In the most recent Windows 10 updates (after 1709) SMBv1 it's not enabled by default:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows

If it's the case, you can try to enable SMBv1 client on Windows machine, but it's not recommended because of serious security issues with this protocol:

https://aka.ms/stopusingsmb1

I believe that the most security approach is to disable SMBv1 and enable SMBv2 on Linux machine. You can try to follow this article:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I already made sure SMB1.0 was enabled on my Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Apparently a few months ago as I was working on our company's security assessment and I was dealing with some vulnerabilities on my Win 10 machine and I changed a registry key and prevented me from mapping a drive to a Linux Samba share that still uses SMBv1.  Although we will be going away from this Server in a few months I still needed to be able to access this Share until the new upgraded server was ready.

The following website shows the registry key that I changed

```
(Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\RequireSecuirySignature)
```

I enabled it by setting the value to 1.

See [Overview of Server Message Block signing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/overview-server-message-block-signing).

Comment: Why don't you just allow Samba to use higher versions of the SMB protocol?